# frustrating behavior with CSS stylesheets

Tags: html, css

I've having a rather stressful issue. I applied a div class called input to style the boxes on my username /password fields like in the picture below.

[image]

However now I want to apply a different styling to the search bar but no matter what I do even If I use a inline style sheet it uses the style of the old input element. I tried pretty much everything.

### login html

```
<div class="form">  

<form name="form1" method="POST" action="login.php">
<div class="input">
  <input name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">

  <input name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" class="submit">


</form>
</div>
```

### search bar html

```
<div class="ajax-div">

    <div class="searchbar">

     <input type="text" onKeyUp="getScriptPage('box','text_content')" id="text_content">

    </div>

    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

### That last width: parameter in input dictates the width of all input bars on the page.

```
.form {

    margin-top:-182px;
    margin-left:1100px;
    position:static;
    width: 220px;
    height:150px;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border: 1px solid #270644;

  background:url(bg-right.png);

}


.label {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        list-style-type: none;
        color: #999;
        text-shadow: #000 1px 1px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        display: block;
    }   




input {
      /* input boxes*/
      -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-box-shadow, background;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
        padding: 6px;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        border-left: 0px;
        border-right: 0px;
        border-top: 1px solid #666;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        background: #FFF;
        width: 130px;

    }
```

the css i'm trying to apply to the search bar:

```
searchbar {

left: 350px;
top:100px;
width: 300px;

}
```

Comment: Is it me or your `searchbar` in CSS should be `.searchbar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try appying the class directly to the input tag **OR** using this CSS -

```
.searchbar input{
// this CSS will only be applied to searchbar input box
left: 350px;
top:100px;
width: 300px;

}
```

The CSS you are trying to apply to searchbar is wrong. Searchbar is the class of the div and not the input box. Try using the CSS above and check if it works

Comment: In this specific case, your CSS works, but I would avoid specifying "input" to style forms. If you had a submit button with your field too, the styles would apply to that also. However, your text box already HAS an ID on it...you should just use this ID. #text_content { STYLES GO HERE }

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you Michael. Though `input[type="text"] {CSS HERE} ` Could also be used

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS selector is wrong.

Instead of this:

```
searchbar {

left: 350px;
top:100px;
width: 300px;

}
```

Try this:

```
.searchbar #text_content {

left: 350px;
top:100px;
width: 300px;

}
```

A 'dot' denotes you want to target a class name. A 'hash' denotes that you want to target a specific ID. CSS has a clue in its name; ***Cascading*** style sheets. Styles "trickle down" from generic to the more specific. Therefore, if you want to target only one single element, then ID's are the way to go...which usually override any generic styles on the elements.

Good luck!

Comment: so by adding a "." and doing .searchbar input that denotes i'm targeting class input and overriding it with the elements provided in searchbar?

Comment: At the moment in your HTML you have this: <div class="searchbar"> to target this tag through CSS you use a dot because it's a class. ".searchbar". However, in your specific case, you want to target your searchbar field ONLY. This field has an ID on it called id="text_content" so I would just simply use #text_content { /* styles here */ }

Answer (score 0):

So, the `searchbar` selector should start with a `.` character and to override the input selector it should probably be `.searchbar input`

And for `input`, you probably want `.input input` as the selector..?

Comment: or.. to obfuscate even further.. .input input[type="text"] ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're using a generic selector for all input fields (Last section of the CSS: input { ..). So the styling will be applied to all inputs.

I'd suggest giving each input it's own class so you can assign different styles for each input. For example.

**CSS**

```
.search
{
    background: red;
}

.login
{
    background: blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="search" />
```

Also, the selector 'searchbar' doesn't select anything as it's targeting an element called searchbar. If you want to target classes you need to target with a . For example: .searchbar

Comment: I'd like to add it's probably a good idea to read up on some CSS basics, either books or tutorials would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

input { } applies styles to all input elements input[type="text"] etc...

Instead apply .input input {} to apply styles for input elements inside input class

To apply styles for input elements inside searchbar use .searchbar input{}